# Weird VS2012 C++ parse

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

**connector.hpp**

```
#ifndef __CONNECTOR_HPP_
#define __CONNECTOR_HPP_

#include <a/b/c/connection.hpp>

namespace a {
    namespace b {
        namespace c {

        class connector {
        public:
            explicit connector(const int port);
            void run();
            void stop();
        };

    }
}
}
#endif
```

**connection.hpp**

```
#ifndef __CONNECTION_HPP_
#define __CONNECTION_HPP_

#include <a/b/c/connector.hpp>

namespace a {
    namespace b {
        namespace c {
                
            class connection {
            private:
              connector owner_; //line 42

            };

        }
    }
}

#endif
```

These simple classes have some trivial (empty) implementations in cpp files.

VS2012 says this when I try to compile this:

> Error 1   error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'owner_'  c:\a\b\c\connection.hpp 42  1   test
>
> Error 2   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   c:\a\b\c\connection.hpp 42  1   test

The thing is that VS editor sees no problems - no red underlines etc.
Include paths are set correctly, I've added `$(SolutionDir)\..\` to includes so that I can use full paths like `a/b/c` instead of relative ones.

Still, this doesnt compile.. but it did once.

**Q: WHY?**

Comment: this adds a 3rd error: `1>c:\a\b\c\connection.hpp(42): error C2039: 'connector' : is not a member of 'a::b::c'`

Comment: This probably doesn't have anything to do with the problem, but identifiers that contain two underscores or begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter are reserved to the implementation. Don't use them. Come up with another convention for your include guards.

Comment: underscores are used in many examples, meh... I just changed them, no difference :(

Comment: Just built on my VS2012 as copy/pasted into a console app without any hiccups.

Comment: @Queequeg - Like Pete said, it probably didn't have anything to do with your problem. However, those leading underscores will kill you eventually. Some programmers see that include guards in system header files inevitably use leading underscores, so this must be the right way to use include guards. Wrong! Those system header files use leading underscores precisely because doing so means their guards won't collide with your guards / your guards won't collide with theirs, but only if you follow the rules. Don't use leading underscores.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson what is my VS2012 doing? Some hidden cache somewhere?

Comment: @Queequeg Either something like that, or you have some invisible character that doesn't copy/paste well in your file.

Comment: Well, I've noticed a circular dependency - please see updated code - what does this change ?!

Comment: That changes everything. Those circular #includes are death.

Comment: but why? can't c++ classes use each other? what are guard `ifdef`s for then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oftentimes those circular `#include` directives are deadly. That's certainly what's happening here. Suppose you `#include "connector.hpp"` in some other file. What's going to happen is that connector.hpp will `#include "connection.hpp"`. This file will in turn `#include "connector.hpp"`, but this is now a no-op because the include guards for connector.hpp are already active. What you end up with is `class connection` being defined before `class connector`. That's a problem because a data member in `class connection` is an instance of `class connector`.

Why is connector.hpp including connection.hpp?

Comment: connector has many connections, connection needs to call some connector (owners) methods ...

Comment: If both classes use the other as instances you are screwed. You have a bad design. You simply cannot do that. On the other hand, if `connector` only uses `connection` through references or pointers, there's an easy solution: Simply forward declare the class `connection` in connector.hpp. The compiler doesn't need to know what's insider that other class. It just needs to know that it **is** a class.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will make separate forward-declaration headers just for this purpose.. I wanted to do this anyway, but .. VS messages made no sense, I had absolutely no idea that **this** is the case.. and this circular dependeny became **visible** only after I've commented out 99% of code -.- Man, I like the power of C++, but issues like this would **never** happen in Java or alike .. ;( VS2012 - new IDE from MS - still NO refactorings, no code analysis... no help whatsoever -.-

Comment: You don't need to make forward declaration headers. At least not any more. All that connector.hpp needs to do is forward declare the class `connection`. If the class `connection` has already been defined, that forward declaration does nothing. No harm, no foul. Re my "at least not anymore": Some compilers used interpret that forward declaration as a signal to erase that class definition. That was sheer stupidity on the part of the compiler. The standard is very clear: Forward declaring a class that has already been declared or defined does nothing.

Comment: Okay. I forward declared `connector` in `connection` header. But I still need to include the definition of connector in connection's cpp, don't I?

Comment: Correct. Class `connection` contains an instance of type `connector`, rather than a pointer to / reference to a `connector`. The definition of class `connector` must be known before you can define class `connection`. There is no escape from this with your current design. That's not necessarily a problem. Problems do arise when the definition of class A mandates that class B already be defined while the definition of class B mandates that class A already be defined. The solution is to steer clear of these circular problems.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me you have include loop.

Namely you include `connection.hpp` in `connector.hpp` and `connector.hpp` in `connection.hpp`

Omit the `#include <a/b/c/connection.hpp>` in connector.hpp

I think the problem might be that the compiler start compiling `connector.hpp` then the prepprocessor sees `#include <a/b/c/connection.hpp>` replaces the `#include` with the contents of the .hpp file (roughly speaking) When it tries to include connector.hpp , it checks the guards and sees that `__CONNECTOR_HPP_` is defined and skips it and since `class connector` is not yet declared it produces this error.

PS: Oh, nevermind, I see it's already answered.